# Set ECDSA on Apache and get SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP

Tags: apache, ssl, encryption, ecdsa

thats my first post.

I will set up an Apache with ECDSA.
I generates this keys
secp256k1 : SECG curve over a 256 bit prime field
secp384r1 : NIST/SECG curve over a 384 bit prime field
and generate a self-signed certificate.

```
openssl ecparam -name secp256k1 -genkey -param_enc explicit -out rootCA.key
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key server.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out rootCA.pem
```

At the ssl.conf I set

```
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
```

Wireshark shows me that the client supports the cipher and i looked at firefox config

The same cipher but with RSA cert works without problems. 
I showed enough Tutorials but i cant find the problem.
www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ this test fails also with "Assessment failed: Failed to communicate with the secure server"

Have someone ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use ECDSA ciphers if you don't present an ECDSA certificate.

```
openssl ecparam -name secp256k1 -genkey -param_enc explicit -out rootCA.key
```

Great this should have created an ECDSA private key. Now you need to make it into a certificate (possibly a self-signed certificate).

But in your following commands, you never use `rootCA.key` to make a certificate. Most probably you have generated an RSA certificate not ECDSA. Try to use `-key rootCA.key` in your `openssl req` command.

Comment: Yes I do this. Generate certificate from private key. Then edit sslconfig and restart apache. I solve my problem with reinstall of apache. I do this and then do the same steps like before.